# Which way do tag synonyms point?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

Below, when I say "main tag" I mean the tag that you want the other tag to redirect to (generally the tag with more votes).  I'll call the tag re-directs to the main tag the "sub-tag."

1. When the [synonyms privileges page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) says it's only possible to create synonyms for tags for which you have five or more rep, does that mean five rep for the sub-tag or main tag?
2. Do I propose a synonym by clicking on the synonyms link in the tag wiki for the main tag or the sub-tag?

Answer (score 2):

1. It means rep for the main tag.
2. You click on the link in the wiki for the main tag and type in the name of the sub-tag.  This suggests a link backwards from the sub-tag to the main tag so that future entries for the sub-tag go to the main tag instead.