# Is the current tag-synonym design hard to use?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I don't think the current site design makes it very clear which direction tag synonyms point.  (If you are encountering the same issue, I've posted [a solution](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1327/which-way-do-tag-synonyms-point).  It took me a while to figure it out.)

Have you also run into problems interpreting tag synonym direction?  Is this issue sufficiently common to be considered a design bug?